# rabbitmq credential issue. only works with localhost

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I have a question regarding rabbitmq. I am trying to set up a messaging system based off the queue name and so far everything has been good with localhost. As soon as I set some credentials for local connection, I get a timeout error. (I have lengthened the timeout time as well.) I have also gave the user administrative privileges and the guest account administrative privileges. I get this error when ran with both the consume and produce script. Port 5672 is open as well. This is all being done on a ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine and python 2.7.14. Guest and my other rabbit user are both allowed to use the default vhost too.

```
import pika, json

credentials = pika.credentials.PlainCredentials('guest', 'guest')
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('<ip here>', 
5672, '/', credentials))
channel = connection.channel()

result = channel.queue_declare(queue='hello', durable=True)  

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        print "localhost received %r" % json.loads(body)


channel.basic_consume(callback,
                  queue='hello')


print 'localhost waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C'
channel.start_consuming()
channel.close()
```

Here is my error message too. Just a timeout method which would make me think that the connection is failing and this is a network problem but when I replace my ip in the credentials with 'localhost', everything works fine. Any ideas?

```
pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed: Connection to <ip here>:5672 failed: timeout
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably running into multiple issues.

First of all, the `guest` user can only connect via `localhost` by default. [This document](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html) goes into detail. FWIW that document is the first hit when `site:rabbitmq.com localhost guest` are used as search terms on google.

Second, `timeout` means that the TCP connection can't be established. Please see [this document](https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-networking.html) for a step-by-step guide to diagnosis.

Comment: I solved the issue. I understand that guest can only be used for localhost. I found out that my syntax for setting permission was wrong and we are using NAT so I was foolishy using the wrong ip.

Comment: Thanks for following up.